# shell_exec and convert pdf to jpg with Imagick PHP

Tags: php, iis, pdf, imagick

I'm using ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2012-06-27 Q16 on a windows 2012 server and with fastcgi and PHP Version 5.4.22.
I'm trying to use this command (inside a PHP file) to convert a pdf to a jpg but it doesn't work, nothing happens.

```
echo shell_exec("convert image.pdf image.jpg");
```

This command line work perfectly inside a command shell (msdos command shell).
I tried to convert a jpg to png and surprisingly it worked !

```
echo shell_exec("convert image.jpg image.png");
```

It's also working when I'm converting a png to pdf.

```
echo shell_exec("convert image.png image.pdf");
```

Now I'm getting confuse, why is it not working from a pdf to an image ?
Am I missing a php extension or a setting ?

Cheers,

Comment: Try changing it to `echo shell_exec("convert image.pdf image.jpg 2>&1");` and show errors if there are any.

Comment: Thank you ! Turns out I have a Postscript delegate failed ...

Comment: And you have your problem solved :D Btw. this trick with `2>&1` redirect command errors from `STDERR` to standard output `STDOUT` so you can see errors in `shell_exec()` output.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put let PHP know the PATH to the ImageMagic.

You can manullay put that by adding this line in your PHP script.

```
putenv("PATH=your_path_to_the_bin_folder");
```

something similar depending on your setup. The gs executable has to be in your script user's path somewhere or ImageMagick will fail to convert PDF or EPS files.

Comment: I already have the environment variables PATH set up for Imagick. What do you mean by script user's path ?

Comment: I hope you have set that path for WINDOWS . But You must let know the PHP about the PATH. To do that you can include the PATH in the PHP Script.

Comment: It's already converting the jpg to png so I guess It's already working ?

Comment: You mean you can do the image conversion via PHP?